# get the max of id and store value in sqlite db

Tags: android

I did some google search and i guess its duplicate, i want to put the value of max if in a variable, how to do that
I have the below query:

```
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


 db.execSQL("select max(id) from tab1");
```

In oracle for example its like this

```
  Select max(id) into numb_var from tab1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select max(id) into numb_var from tab1",null);
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                         maxID = cursor.getInt(0);
                         cursor.moveToNext();
                   }
                  cursor.close();
        }
}
```

you'll have max in maxID variable.

Comment: When i write it the way you posted, the app is not opening

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int id = 0;
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select max(id) as id from tab1", null);
while(c.moveToNext()) {
     id = c.getInt(0);
}
//you have your id stored in id variable
```